# C++ Delete Duplicate Entries in a vector

Tags: c++, std

I have a vector of times, and there are a number of places where the time is duplicated. The time vector is only one column of data from a text file, there are several other vectors (velocity, position, etc) from the same data text file. How do I go about deleting the duplicate entries based on time, while maintaining all the other entries? Say:

```
if (time[j] == time[j + 1]
{
    do stuff...
}
```

I actually have several vectors, so I will be deleting the duplicate entries from them as well. I need to preserve the order of data in the other vectors (they are not necessarily consecutive.)

I only want to delete consecutive duplicate points.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only want to delete _consectutive_ duplicates, or all duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a cute way you could do it is to sort the vector using std::sort, and then you can use std::unique to remove consecutive duplicates from the vectors whole range (.begin() to .end()).

You can probably find a more efficient way, but this is an interesting one at least and will only require 2 lines of code :)

Comment: I actually have several vectors, so I will be deleting the duplicate entries from them as well. I need to preserve the order of data in the other vectors (they are not necessarily consecutive.)

Answer (score 1):

As you say duplicates follow eachother you can use this variation on the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), otherwise you'd have to sort first (see [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) or [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort))

```
time.erase(std::unique(time.begin(),time.end()),time.end());
```

Comment: @user1187621: you have to include the `<algorithm>` header. Afaik it's a pre-c++11 library so VS2010 should have it (can't verify myself though).

Comment: this works, except when I go and use this method on the other vectors, I end up deleting more "duplicate" data points than I do out of the time vector. I only want to delete consecutive duplicate points.

Comment: @user1187621 I don't know exactly what you mean with the other arrays without a concrete example, but if you need data to still be linked, you should really put them in the same vector (using a struct, `std::tuple` or whatever you like). Also if you do not sort, this will only remove consecutive duplicates...

Comment: I don't think I am sorting. How would I do this with a STRUCT?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just avoid adding duplicates to begin with? I.E. check to see if the item already exists before adding it to the vector.

Comment: I'm reading in the data from a text file, and the way I'm reading it in isn't really set up to check if the values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If ordering must be preserved and duplicates are not consecutive:

```
{
    auto i = time.begin()
    std::set<time::value_type> exists;
    while(i != time.end()) {
        if (exists.insert(*i).second == false)  //it's a duplicate:
            i = time.erase(i);
        else //else not a duplicate
            ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just copying the data to a new vector, and deleting duplicate entries along the way.