# Efficiently delete double entries in C++ STL vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Delete Duplicate Entries in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366291/c-delete-duplicate-entries-in-a-vector)

I need to delete double entries in C++ STL vectors. An important point is that the order of elements in the resulting vector must be equivalent to the order in the input vector. Is there an algorithm (e.g. in stl, boost) which would do this?

Comment: `std::unique` requires that all double entries are in continuous order. This is an assumption I cannot fulfill in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible cases here: either the vector is already sorted or it isn't.

If it is, `std::erase` and `std::unique` can easily solve this as shown in the other answers.

If it isn't then you can do achieve the goal with

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate), v.end());
```

but there's a problem in that `predicate` is not trivial to specify: it's a function that accepts one argument (the value to consider) and it needs to answer the question "is there any equal value earlier in the vector?". Since you aren't told where exactly in the vector the supplied argument is, that means you 'd have to keep quite a bit of manual state to be able to answer this.

A convenient option here would be to use an `std::set` to do some of the heavy lifting:

```
std::set<decltype(v)::value_type> set(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        v.begin(), 
        v.end(), 
        [&set] (decltype(v)::value_type item) { return !set.erase(item); }), 
    v.end());
```

What this does is prepopulate an `std::set` with the values in the vector and then check if an item has been seen before by seeing if it has been removed from the set. This way the result will retain only the first item from each set of items that compare equal in the input.

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/zJNF0T).

Answer (score 4):

If your vector is not sorted and you thus cannot just use `std::unique` (and likewise cannot sort it which would destroy your order), you can use something like this function (using C++11 lambdas):

```
template<typename FwdIt> FwdIt unordered_unique(FwdIt first, FwdIt last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIt>::value_type value_type;
    std::set<value_type> unique;
    return std::remove_if(first, last, [&unique](const value_type &arg) { 
                                           return !unique.insert(arg).second; });
}
```

Which can be invoke using the usual erase-romve-idiom:

```
v.erase(unordered_unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

Of course you can also use C++11's `std::unordered_set` instead of a `std::set` (for hashable types, of course) to get away from O(n log n) in average case.

Answer (score 1):

How about `std::unique`?

```
auto firstDup = std::unique(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use next:
`vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );`

Comment: This assumes that the vector is sorted.